# Rest Client gives Bad Request for HTTP PUT request

Tags: rest, http, jersey, jax-rs, put

I'm new to Rest Client development. Need your help in figuring out how to get a proper response for below rest service.

```bash
curl --location --request PUT 'sandbox-url/TokenGeneratorAPI/v1/update_pay_status' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --header 'Authorization: Basic {{token}' \
    --data-raw '{
        "pay_id":000000000,
        "status":1,
        "amount":0.00,
        "pay_method":0,
        "pay_sys_ref":"test"
    }'
```

I created a class in client side for request object like below.

```java
public class PaymentRqBean {
   
    @XmlElement(name="pay_id")
    String pay_id;
    @XmlElement(name="status")
    String status;
    @XmlElement(name="amount")
    String amount;
    @XmlElement(name="pay_method")
    String pay_method; 
    @XmlElement(name="pay_sys_ref")
    String pay_sys_ref;

    public String getPay_id() {
        return pay_id;
    }

    public void setPay_id(String pay_id) {
        this.pay_id = pay_id;
    }
}
```

......and getters setters for other attributes

And created a method for calling the web service in another class like below.

```java
public PaymentRsBean callWS(PaymentRqBean pReq) {
     PaymentRsBean prs = new PaymentRsBean();
     Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
     client.register(new Authenticator(com.boc.conf.Configurations.objProperty.getProperty("ikUserName"), com.boc.conf.Configurations.objProperty.getProperty("ikPassword")));
        
     WebTarget webTarget = client.target(url);
     Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
     Response response = invocationBuilder.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).put(Entity.json(pReq));
```

I'm getting **HTTP 400 BAD REQUEST** for above.  I would be so thankful for any help given in solving this.

(Is it because @XmlRootElement? )

Comment: Is there no error message?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way you are defining the attributes of your PaymentRqBean class.
The `variables` 'pay_id', 'status', 'amount' and 'pay_method' must be of numeric type (`int`, `double`...), since the request you launch indicates that they are numeric, not `Strings`.

```
 "pay_id":000000000,
        "status":1,
        "amount":0.00,
        "pay_method":0
```